# Python: Fitting copula to time series Data and placing new data within distribution

Tags: python-3.x, time-series

I am importing price data and looking to fit those within a copula created from historical data, I was originally using packages copulalib (copulas can also be used) to create a copula (in this case Gumbel) but i am unable to place my new price data on the distribution.
When generating u, v from these packages it uses random numbers pulled from the uniform distribution is there a way to do this with pricing data?

Comment: I suggest to provide sample data and links to the packages you mention. I guess that the package generates a random vector (u,v) with uniform marginals and Gumbel copula. According to Sklar's theorem, the vector you need is (X,Y)=(F^-1(U),G^-1(V)), where F and G are the marginal distributions of X and Y: what marginals are required in your pricing dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Without any data provided in the question, I propose to create a sample from a Gumbel copula with theta = 2 then try to fit a Gumbel copula to the sample obtained in order to guess theta

```
import openturns as ot

theta = 2
Original_copula = ot.GumbelCopula(theta)
sample = Original_copula.getSample(500)

# Fitting of a Gumbel copula
Fitted_distribution = ot.GumbelCopulaFactory().build(sample)
print("Guessed theta =", Fitted_distribution.getParameter()[0])
>>> Guessed theta = 2.1805628386645686
```

for sample size of 5000, I obtain
Guessed theta = 2.0099533501045226

[More available OpenTURNS Copulas here](https://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/probabilistic_modelling.html)

Answer (score 0):

With the `distfit` library you can fit the distribution on your pricing historical data, and then you can use the `predict` function to make predictions on new unseen samples. See more documentation [here](https://erdogant.github.io/distfit/pages/html/Examples.html#make-predictions). The predict function returns a P-value with multiple test correction. A small example with some demo data:

```
# Example data
X = np.random.normal(10, 3, 2000)
y = [3,4,5,6,10,11,12,18,20]

# From the distfit library import the class distfit
from distfit import distfit

# Initialize
dfit = distfit(todf=True)

# Search for best theoretical fit on your empirical data
dfit.fit_transform(X)

# Make prediction on new datapoints based on the fit
results = dfit.predict(y)

# The plot function will now also include the predictions of y
dfit.plot()
```

The results are:

```
results['df']

      y   y_proba y_pred         P
0   3.0  0.023792   down  0.007931
1   4.0  0.044730   down  0.019880
2   5.0  0.079661   down  0.044256
3   6.0  0.131986   none  0.087990
4  10.0  0.492335   none  0.492335
5  11.0  0.406206   none  0.361072
6  12.0  0.315383   none  0.245298
7  18.0  0.018689     up  0.004153
8  20.0  0.004836     up  0.000537
```

[image]